# Create new column in data.table by group

Tags: r, vector, data.table

I have no experience with data.table, so I don't know if there is a solution to my question (30 minutes on Google gave no answer at least), but here it goes.

With data.frame I often use the following command to check the number of observations of a unique value:

```
df$Obs=with(df, ave(v1, ID-Date, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

Is there any corresponding method when working with data.table?

Comment: There Definitely are specific methods for data.tables. See the [vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) and the [faqs](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) for that package!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is. Happily, you've asked about one of the newest features of `data.table`, added in v1.8.2 :

> `:=` by group is now implemented (FR#1491) and sub-assigning to a new column
>       by reference now adds the column automatically (initialized with `NA` where
>       the sub-assign doesn't touch) (FR#1997). `:=` by group can be combined with all
>       types of `i`, so *`:=` by group* includes grouping by `i` as well as by `by`.
>       Since `:=` by group is by reference, it should be significantly faster than any
>       method that (directly or indirectly) `cbind`s the grouped results to DT, since
>       no copy of the (large) DT is made at all. It's a short and natural syntax that
>       can be compounded with other queries.
>       `DT[,newcol:=sum(colB),by=colA]`

In your example, iiuc, it should be something like :

```
DT[, Obs:=.N, by=ID-Date]
```

instead of :

```
df$Obs=with(df, ave(v1, ID-Date, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

Note that `:=` by group scales well for large data sets (and smaller datasets will a lot of small groups).

See `?":="` and [Search data.table tag for "reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5C%5Bdata.table%5C%5D%20reference)